# Admob Error: Not enough space to show ad. Needs 320x50 dp, but only has 309x0 dp

Tags: android, admob

I am trying to ad smart banner ads to my fragment layout and all I am getting incesantly is "Not enough space to show ad. Needs 320x50 dp, but only has 309x0 dp".

This is my fragment layout.

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/details_layout"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.app.bookng.DetailsFragment">

    <RelativeLayout

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/details_relat"
        android:padding="5dp">

        <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:id="@+id/banner_id"
            ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
            ads:adUnitId="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"/>

        <ProgressBar
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:indeterminate="true"
            android:id="@+id/progress_circle"
            android:visibility="gone"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:hint="@string/title"
            android:id="@+id/dbook_title"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/dbook_title"
            android:id="@+id/rootauthor_date"
            android:gravity="center_vertical">

            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:visibility="gone"
                android:background="#d1d1d1"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:id="@+id/dviewtop"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/author_img"/>


            <com.app.bookng.CircularNetworkImageView
                android:layout_width="90dp"
                android:layout_height="90dp"
                android:visibility="gone"
                android:padding="3dp"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:id="@+id/author_img"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:background="@drawable/round_button"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:visibility="gone"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/author_img"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/dviewtop"
                android:id="@+id/author_date"/>



            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:visibility="gone"
                android:background="#d1d1d1"
                android:id="@+id/dviewbottom"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/author_date"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/author_img"/>
        </RelativeLayout>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/rootauthor_date"
            android:hint="@string/main_body"
            android:textColorLink="@color/textlink"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:id="@+id/dbook_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"/>


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/gad_title"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/gad_pic"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:layout_below="@+id/gad_title"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/gad_feat"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:layout_below="@+id/gad_pic"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:layout_below="@+id/gad_feat"
            android:id="@+id/gad_content"/>

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:background="#d1d1d1"
            android:id="@+id/viewtop_share"
            android:layout_below="@+id/dbook_content"/>


        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/viewtop_share"
            android:id="@+id/comment_container"/>

    </RelativeLayout>


</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

And this is the acivity layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

     //Container for toolbar    
    <include layout="@layout/post_toolbar"/>

    //Container for fragment    
    <include layout="@layout/share_layout"/>


</FrameLayout>
```

I really can't figure out why the height is 0dp. Please can you help me?

Comment: try removing the `android:padding="5dp"` from your relative layout

Comment: @Shubhank surprisingly this fixed it. Please enter it as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

According to Admob docs/guidelines

The ad view require to be of full width of the device.
Since you give the `padding` to your layout it fails because it can't fill full width of the layout.

You just have to remove the padding in your `RelativeLayout` to fix this

Comment: thanks for the fix , can you let me know how did you find this out.

Comment: @user2548816 have a look here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/android/banner

Answer (score 1):

Replace SMART_BANNER for BANNER. Can't get easier.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue when the adSize was SMART_BANNER replacing it with LARGE_BANNER or BANNER fixed the problem. SMART_BANNER ads are displayed with the device width. If your ad's layout width is less than the device width, it results in the error "Not enough space to show ad"

Answer (score -1):

put this in your android manifest.xml

```
<activity android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"> </activity>
```